# Is it possible to create a batch file which switches the "monitoring" of the microphone on/off in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, batch-file, monitoring, microphone

So when I right click on the speaker icon in the bottom right of my Windows screen and go to "Recording equipment" (dunno if it is the right english name in Windows); then right click on "Microphone" -> "Properties"
and finally to "custom". There is a checkbox called "Monitoring".

Here's is a short Album on imgur of the separated steps

[http://imgur.com/a/DIGa7](https://imgur.com/a/DIGa7)

So why would I do this? I often switch between my headset and my surround system. When the surround system is active I want the monitoring off because I eventually get in a feedback loop and the sound has a little "echo" which sounds quite odd. And when I'm on my headset I want to hear my "surroundings" so that if I get called or the doorbell rings I am able to hear it.
The way I do this now is pretty much like the screenshots. It gets kind of annoying doing this every time, and switch to flip it on/off would be great!

So, is this possible, and if yes, how?

I tracked down the regristry to this point:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture{ddbc6499-3927-4fb7-a643-b1265565ecca}\Properties

And within this folder there is the Mikrofon of my ASUS Xonar DX Audio Device. I'm not sure, whether I am in the right spot or not, but it's a beginning.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I can't exactly remember how, but this should be just as easy as disabling the microphone device with a switch applied to a "start devmgr.msc" command.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with Powershell. There is a fantastic technet blog by Natalia Mackevicius [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/). Have a read and then try the below. *You can either set this to run as part of a scheduled task or you can run it manually (with the correct permissions).*

> Download the cmdlet here:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388

> Find the device driver you wish to disable and run the following:

```
Import-Module .\PSCmdlet.psd1 –Verbose
$deviceName = Read-Host -Prompt ‘Please enter the Name of the Device to Disable’; Get-Device | Where-Object -Property Name -Like $deviceName | Disable-Device
```